# One barrier for multiple go routines

Tags: go, goroutine, barrier

I am experimenting with go routines.

I have a go routine function executed x times, and I want to wait for all of theses routines to continue in my main function. I've try to use chan for the barrier.

I've try something like that:

```
func goroutine(i int, ch []chan bool) {
    //do stuff
    ch[i] <- true
}

func main() {
    var ch []chan bool
    for i := 0; i < nb; i++ {
        ch[i] = make(chan bool)
        go goroutine(i, ch)
    }

    // wait to continue
    for i := 0; i < nb; i++ {
         <- ch[i]
    }
}
```

I have the following error : `panic: runtime error: index out of range` for the line `ch[i] = make(chan bool)`

First question:

- is the good solution to use chan ?

Second question:

- Why do I have this index out of range error ?

Comment: You're never allocating `ch`. Normally though one would just use a `sync.WaitGroup` for this. Maybe some of the links at the end of the Tour Of Go section on concurrency will help: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to wait for the goroutines to complete and don't need to get a result back over the channel, then `sync.WaitGroup` would be a cleaner solution. The way that would work is:

- Create a WaitGroup wg and whenever you start a goroutine call `wg.Add(1)` and pass a pointer to the wg to the goroutine.
- In the goroutine, before returning call `wg.Done()`
- To wait for all the goroutines to finish, call `wg.Wait()`

Comment: Thanks. I just read the documentation about sync.WaitGroup. It is the solution I will use